# Swift 3 Reading Json from local : Argument label '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overload

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Please help me. I spent many days to solve it but I still can not.

I want to read Json file from local using swift 3.

I got error like in the image below. 
[image: Error Image]

Thank you before hand

Comment: Don't post images. Post code (text)!

Answer (score 1):

The method to init a Data object with the content of a file is

```
init(contentsOf url: URL, options: Data.ReadingOptions = default)
```

You see the difference?

- contentsOf instead of contentsOfFile
- missing the 'options:' parameter.

Comment: let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
        let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: Data.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped)
        let dicJSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        print(dicJSON)

Answer (score 0):

You can read JSON file from local like below

```
func getContentsFromJsonFile() {
  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fileName", ofType: "json")
  let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: Data.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped)
  let dicJSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: []) as! [String: Any]         
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parth Adroja. Now it work fine. I am so happy.

Comment: let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "json")
            let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path!), options: Data.ReadingOptions.dataReadingMapped)

        let dicJSON = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])
        print(dicJSON)